# python manage.py runserver not respoding

Tags: python, django, loading

[right after i entered python manage.py runserver - nothing appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcElN.png)

[when i entered ctrl+c, then these messages appear - (server doesnt run when i enter localhost:8080](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHoim.png)

hello, i am a student who just started studing django, right after i created my project and added one html code then tried to run my server,

`python manage.py runserver` or `python manage.py runserver 8080` does not work

if I type in the terminal  `python manage.py runserver` ,

it just keeps on loading and doesnt show anything and server doesnt run even after so many hours.

*

> nothing appears after waiting for long time  so it i press ctrl+c to
>   stop running the server!!
>
> **THEN** after i pressed ctrl+c, the following meassages(system performing check...)(PLEASE CHECK
>   THE IMAGE ABOVE) appear (**ONLY WHEN I PRESS CTRL+C**) on my bash screen even though the server didnt run at all

*
+) i have not entered much code yet related to migration

**python version 3.7.0**

**django version 2.1.7**

Comment: Try `python manage.py migrate`, though that probably shouldn't prevent the server from starting for several hours. What happens if you start the server and open `http://127.0.0.1:8080` in your browser?

Comment: Your question is unclear. That screenshot shows that the server has indeed started. What else are you expecting?

Comment: Doesnt work for me either. The server starts, but the pages wont load. As I mentioned in the answer below, maybe its because 8080 is reserved for HTTP traffic?

Comment: Your screenshot shows that your server did start ("starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8080/"). What happens when you browse to http://127.0.0.1:8080/? What do you see in your browser and what do you see in your console?

Comment: ive editted my question for clearer info thank you

Comment: @DanielRoseman these messages appear when i press ctrl+c and doesnt appear when i runserver. i editted my question sorry for the unclear question thank you

Comment: @dirkgroten this message appears ONLY WHEN i quit my server(ctrl+C) also after i runserver, my browser doesnt show anything

Comment: what OS are you on? What shell are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try below run command:

```
python manage.py runserver 0:8080
```

Add 8080 in UFW rules, if firewall is active